# Return undefined class javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, class, return-value

Help me please, I have a problem. Here is my code:

```
function Cnx() {
    var url = 'http://192.168.0.13/activity?name=flower';
    var solicitud = new XMLHttpRequest();
    this.res;
    solicitud.addEventListener('load', cargar, false);

    solicitud.open("GET", url, true);
    solicitud.send(null);

    function cargar(e) {
        this.setRes(e.target.responseText);
    }

    this.setRes = function(valor) {
        this.res = valor;
    }

    this.getRes = function() {
        alert(this.res);
    }

}
```

Then, I call:

`var cnx= New Cnx();
alert(cnx.getRes());`

But, this returns undefined. If I call for example cnx.getRes() from a button it's returns the correct value.

Note: The ajax call works fine.

Why this happens?

Thank you very much advance. I'm sorry my bad English...

Comment: Perhaps because `getRes` doesn't return anything?

Comment: Whats your actual `e.target.responseText` output? Try `console.log(e.target.responseText);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides Ed's observation there is another issue:

The control flow won't wait for the XMLHttpRequest to finish after calling `New Cnx();`. So the response will never be available, if you don't wait for the request to finish before calling `cnx.getRes()`.

The best thing you could do is to put the rest of you code inside your `cargar` function, which will automatically be called, as soon as the response has been loaded.

Comment: thanks're absolutely right, I fixed my script and it works correctly.

Comment: +1 for the good catch.

Answer (score 0):

`getRes()` doesn't have a return value, so the return value is undefined.

Comment: YMMD's answer is also correct; you will need to fix both problems.